# Run-time Error 5825: Object has been deleted for .docm import

Tags: excel, forms, import, ms-word

Good day,

I'm pretty new to VBA. I have a .docm form which I would like to read into an excel spreadsheet. The form has both legacy controls and newer controls. I found code which would import the data from the .docm document into Excel, but it gives me an error message at the line `WkSht.Cells(i, j) = .Result`. I am truly at a loss because I'm not sure why it was deleted. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub GetFormData()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model.
'See under the VBE's Tools|References.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim FmFld As Word.FormField, CCtrl As Word.ContentControl
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim WkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Set WkSht = ActiveSheet
i = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.docm", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  i = i + 1
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    j = 0
    For Each FmFld In .FormFields
      j = j + 1
      With FmFld
        Select Case .Type
          Case Is = wdFieldFormCheckBox
            WkSht.Cells(i, j) = .CheckBox.Value
          Case Else
            WkSht.Cells(i, j) = .Result
        End Select
      End With
    Next
    For Each CCtrl In .ContentControls
      j = j + 1
      With CCtrl
        Select Case .Type
          Case Is = wdContentControlCheckBox
            WkSht.Cells(i, j) = .Checked
          Case wdContentControlDate, wdContentControlDropdownList, wdContentControlRichText, wdContentControlText
            WkSht.Cells(i, j) = .Range.Text
          Case Else
        End Select
      End With
    Next
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: That is some code I wrote! The only reason I can see that you might get an error with 'WkSht.Cells(i, j) = .Result' is if you're trying to read the contents of a dropdown formfield that has no dropdown selection items to choose from (i.e. it's completely empty).

Comment: Thank you so much for your code! I appreciate it so much. After the form was first developed, they had asked me to create dependent drop down lists. It seems that it is the nature of such lists to be empty if nothing in the "independent" drop down list is selected. I had to make five dependent drop downs, and the user may not necessarily need to fill out all of them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use:

```
On Error Resume Next
WkSht.Cells(i, j) = .Result
On Error Goto 0
```

To process ActiveX controls, you would need to add code like:

```
Dim iShp As Word.InlineShape
```

to the variable declarations at the top of the code, then code like:

```
    For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
      j = j + 1
      With iShp
        If .Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
          With .OLEFormat
            Select Case Split(.ClassType, ".")(1)
              Case Is = "TextBox", "ComboBox", "ListBox"
                WkSht.Cells(i, j) = .Object
              Case "CheckBox", "OptionButton"
                WkSht.Cells(i, j) = .Object
              Case Else
            End Select
          End With
        End If
      End With
    Next
```

after the final existing 'Next' in the code.

Comment: It's giving me a syntax error on `On Error Goto Next` (so sorry, but I really am new to VBA).

Comment: Sorry, that should have been 'On Error Resume Next'. Fixed.

Comment: So close! I was able to get everything out except the yes/no option groups. Is that possible, too?

Comment: Your reference to "yes/no option groups" is ambiguous. Please explain what these are.

Comment: I made 2 groups of legacy control option buttons (each with an option button labelled yes or no). I searched the exported data (which worked wonderfully for everything else, thank you very much!) but I could not find any data pertaining to those controls. Thoughts? And thank you so much for your patience!

Comment: Your description suggests you have ActiveX controls in the document, which the original code didn't process. See updated answer.

Comment: Macropod, thank you so much! I appreciate it as I wouldn't have had a clue. It worked wonderfully! All the best to you!